# VisioForge distributable, cannot find dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, gac

We are using VisioForge .NET Media Player in our application, we've used various versions of it or years and this week we decided to upgrade to version 8.

We are having trouble distributing their DLL's with our application so we created a simple WinForm which only references their control.

On doing do we the error :

> Unable to load DLL 'VisioForge_MFP.dll': The specified module could
>   not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

We're not strangers to using 3rd party components, however the standard practices don't appear to change anything.

So far we've tried:

- Copying into application directory
- Copying to system32
- Using regsvr32 to register them (failed with error)
- Registering in the GAC (No assembly reference error)
- Copying every single distributable component that comes in the package to the application folder.

Still the same message.

The only requirements from the supplier is

1. Must have c++ x86 SP1 distro installed (we have)

The supplier's support team are shall we say, intermittent. Their website / documentation isn't clear.

On the development machine which has the SDK installed, as expected it all loads / works fine.

Can anyone advise any other way to reference this DLL we could be missing?

Target OS is Win 7 & Embedded X86, which is not 'limited' it's a full install of all components.

Answer (score 0):

After several emails with their support 'team', turns out the fault was with the DLL itself.

An update was provided which resolved the issue.

Comment: hello Damo, I'm having the same problem. How could you resolve it? who provided the update for you?

Comment: It was Roman at VisioForge. You need the updated DLL from them.